# 30 positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given any $30$ positive integers we can find some integers so their sum is divided by $30$.

I don't have any idea where to start. First I would like just some hints, then If possible I would like do discuss different ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Hang on a second: "Given any 30 positive integers we can find some integers so their sum is divided by 30" sounds incomplete. Do you mean that their sum is _divisible_ by 30?

Comment: Welcome kk211 ! Improve your 1st post to get helped. What is the question ?

Comment: @igael: I would say it is perfectly clear what the question is. You and Sean should make allowances for non-native English speakers.

Comment: @TonyK: it is between non english speakers , I use many times a translator :) I mean that I don't understand the question because I don't see what it is : a probability ? the possibility of ?

Comment: @igael: Oh, OK. The question is: How do we prove that there must be some non-empty subset of these $30$ integers whose sum is divisible by $30$?

Comment: @TonyK: edit the message, this will help kk211

Comment: A good place to start is with a simplified version of such a problem, e.g. how many integers are needed to be able to force a subset whose sum is divisible by two?  By the way, it should be a nonempty subset we require since a zero sum is divisible by anything.

Comment: finally, edited , it is a good question ...

Answer (score 6):

Let the numbers be $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_{30}$. Now consider the $31$ numbers

$0$
$n_1 \mod 30$
$n_1+n_2 \mod 30$
$\ldots$
$n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_{30} \mod 30$

Given $31$ non-negative integers, all less than $30$, what can you say about their distribution? And how does that answer your question? If you are stuck, look up the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).